# scanning a double and char value at same time

Tags: java

`Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
 do {
     System.out.println(userInput.nextDouble());
 } while(true);`

what to do, when I'm printing double numbers but I want to break this loop after a user enters 'k' character?

Comment: This is a Q+A site. Do you have a question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not entirely clear what problem you're facing but I assume what you want is to read the next token via `next()` or `nextLine()` and parse it yourself. Additionally please read [ask] for info on how to improve your question.

Comment: You want to read in the value as double and afterwards determine if it is a char? Your input can be of different types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate what next input is, a possible solution for your case would be:

```
boolean doscan=true;
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    if(userInput.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println(userInput.nextDouble());
    } else if (userInput.next().equals("k")){
        doscan=false;
    }
} while(doscan);
```